# Prevent service being destroyed

Tags: android, service

I have the necessity to start a permanent service that execute some tasks every x hour. I've implemented it in the follow way:
MainActivity

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BootReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarm != null) {
        alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pintent);
    }
```

Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d("Testing", "Service got created");
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyService.onCreate()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("Testing", "Service got destroyed");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    Toast.makeText(this, "MyService.onStart()", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("Testing", "Service got started");


    new AsyncNotify().execute(this);


    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    Log.d("Testing", "Service got task removed");

    Log.d("Testing", "TASK REMOVED");

    PendingIntent service = PendingIntent.getService(
            getApplicationContext(),
            1001,
            new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyService.class),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 5000, service);
}
```

}

Broadcast receiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        if (alarm != null) {
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, 60000,
                    pintent);
        }

}
```

}

The problem is that when I close the app, the broadcastreceiver continues to be active but the Service enter in OnDestroyed and so the broadcastreceiver can't call the Service.

EDIT try with WorkManager.

Mainactivity:

```
WorkManager wm = WorkManager.getInstance();

    PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    if (wm != null) {
        wm.enqueue(periodicWork);
    }
```

Worker:

```
public class MyWorker extends Worker {

public MyWorker() {}

@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    Log.d("Testing", "OK");
    return Result.SUCCESS;
}
```

}

Now the problem is that the work is executed only the first time and then nothing.

Comment: use jobscheduler/workmanager or similar to schedular recurring tasks. Do not attempt to keep a service alive forever. It is not feasible and not battery friendly

Comment: Yes, I've edited with this solution but the work is executed only the first time.

Comment: I don't know how you tested that. It is possible that the minimum interval is higher than your testing interval

Comment: Mmm yes it could be. Is there a way to test it quickly? Or have I to wait an hour for every test? :D

Comment: it is probably documented. Check the developer site

Comment: Yes, the minimum interval mentioned by you is pretty small. It's below the one required.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 8.0, services are not allowed to be persistently running in background, this includes `AlarmManager` callbacks as well.

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes) migration doc once.

**Solution**: For apps targeting android 26 and above, it's recommended to use `WorkManager` [link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) for background tasks.

In your problem context, you can probably use a `PeriodicWorkRequest`, it works like a charm!

Comment: I've already tryed with PeriodicWorkRequest, but the problem is that do only the first workrequest and then nothing.

Comment: Are you sure? JobScheduler calls it internally on every periodic time given. And workmanager is a wrapper around it, so it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [PeriodicWorkRequest GitHub demo](https://github.com/patelviraj/WorkManagerDayCounter) which updates day counter once in a day (every 24 hours) during the maintenance window. It executes doWork() method, whether the application is open or closed.

WorkManager version **1.0.0-alpha04** is recently introduce and still, it is in alpha mode so it will work completely for all devices once they release the final version.

Comment: PeriodicWorkRequest periodicWork = new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class, 60,
            TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build(); - PeriodicWorkRequest required minimum 15 Minute interval. Given intervel will set it to default MIN_PERIODIC_INTERVAL_MILLIS interval. Refer: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/PeriodicWorkRequest